# Flex empty mx:AdvansedDataGrid after add columns increase her size

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a AdvansedDatGrid with empty data and more columns. Grid has width and height equals to 100 percent. I put this grid in group with 100 persentage width and height. If i add some columns, the data grid change her size and size of parent container. If i put some data in dataProvider, than grid resize rightly, bug appear only if grid has not data.

In this code block creates AdvancedDataGrid with 59 columns without data in dataGrid. Her width equals 5900px. Click on button "Add Columns" add 10 columns to Grid. After than, grid increase her size on 1000px, and size of parent container(testGroup).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               initialize="application1_initializeHandler(event)"
               width="100%" height="100%">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridColumn;

        [Bindable]
        private var columnsData:Array = [];
        //Create columns with number header
        private function createColumnsData():void {
                        var tempColumn:AdvancedDataGridColumn;

                        for (var i:int = 0; i < 59; i++) {
                            tempColumn = new AdvancedDataGridColumn(Math.floor(Math.random() * 200).toString());
                            tempColumn.headerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000).toString();
                            tempColumn.dataField = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200).toString();
                            columnsData.push(tempColumn);
                        }

                        dataGrid.columns = columnsData;
                    }

                    private function addColumns():void {
                        var tempColumn:AdvancedDataGridColumn;

                        for (var i:int = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                            tempColumn = new AdvancedDataGridColumn(Math.floor(Math.random() * 200).toString());
                            tempColumn.headerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000).toString();
                            tempColumn.dataField = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200).toString();
                            columnsData.push(tempColumn);
                        }

                        dataGrid.columns = columnsData;
                    }
        private function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            addColumns();
        }
        protected function application1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
    addColumns();
        }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
        <s:Group id="testGroup" width="100%" height="100%">            
              <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dataGrid"
                                           horizontalScrollPolicy="auto"
                                           width="100%" height="100%"
                                           columns="{columnsData}"/>
              <s:HGroup paddingBottom="10" paddingTop="10">
                <s:Button label="Add Columns" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
              </s:HGroup>
        </s:Group>
</s:Application>
```

I saw in Flex bugs database and didn't find any point, abiut this issue. I use Flex SDK 4.1.0. But this problem appear in Fles SDK 4.6.0.

I try to repair this bug set the direct width to Grid. This looks fine and bug disappear, but if i decrease size of application, the data grid didn't decrease her size, because he has direct width instead percentWidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution:

1. set direct width to grid
2. add resize listener

   ```
           [Bindable]
           private var columnsData:Array = [];
           //Create columns with number header
           private function createColumnsData():void {
               var tempColumn:AdvancedDataGridColumn;

               for (var i:int = 0; i < 59; i++) {
                   tempColumn = new AdvancedDataGridColumn(Math.floor(Math.random() * 200).toString());
                   tempColumn.headerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000).toString();
                   tempColumn.dataField = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200).toString();
                   columnsData.push(tempColumn);
               }

               dataGrid.columns = columnsData;
           }

           private function addColumns():void {
               var tempColumn:AdvancedDataGridColumn;

               for (var i:int = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                   tempColumn = new AdvancedDataGridColumn(Math.floor(Math.random() * 200).toString());
                   tempColumn.headerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000).toString();
                   tempColumn.dataField = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200).toString();
                   columnsData.push(tempColumn);
               }

               dataGrid.columns = columnsData;
           }
           private function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
               addColumns();
           }

           protected function application1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
               addColumns();
           }

           protected function contentGroup_resizeHandler(event:ResizeEvent):void
           {
               if (this.width < dataGrid.getExplicitOrMeasuredWidth()) {
                   dataGrid.width = this.width;
               }
           }
       ]]>
   </fx:Script>
   <s:VGroup id="testGroup" 
            resize="contentGroup_resizeHandler(event)"
            width="100%" height="100%">            
       <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dataGrid"
                            horizontalScrollPolicy="auto"
                            width="{testGroup.width}" height="100%"
                            columns="{columnsData}"/>
       <s:HGroup paddingBottom="10" paddingTop="10">
           <s:Button label="Add Columns" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
       </s:HGroup>
   </s:VGroup>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add a Resize listener to the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           width="100%" height="100%"
           resize="onResize(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    onResize(e:ResizeEvent):void {
        dataGrid.width=this.width;
    }
    //etc...
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Make sure your dataGrid always has a direct width set, and it'll always get set to the same size as the application, no matter how you resize it.

Comment: This doesn't help, becouse then i insert columns to grid, all application increase her size and this.width will be equal dataGrid.width

Comment: Are you building this as AIR or as Flex for a web page?

Comment: This is Flex web application. I found several solution for this problem(set vertical layout for all application elements or set direct size for grid, but this decision create new problems...), but this didn't help me becouse of application structure, but this is no matter.